# Deleting copy/move constructor for singleton class in cpp

Tags: c++, singleton, copy-constructor

The below code snip from a singleton class(claiming to be!!) is used for returning the singleton instance of the class using reference. The copy/move constructors were not marked as deleted in this case.

```
    static SingletonTestClass& getInstance() {
        static SingletonTestClass handler;
        return handler;
    }
```

And there were two flavours of usages as follows

1. Getting the instance to a local variable and use that to invoke class functions

```
    auto handler = SingletonTestClass::getInstance();
    handler.someApi();
```

2. Directly calling the "someApi" like shown below.

```
    SingletonTestClass::getInstance().someApi();
```

For case 1 there is a copy constructor involved wherein in case of 2 its not. I am interested in knowing how case 2 is working inernally.

Note:
I have refactored the original code to the following style assuming this is a good way of implementing singleton and would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
    public:
    static SingletonTestClass* getInstance() {
        static SingletonTestClass handler;
        return &handler;
    }

    /* Note: Do not provide copy/move semantics */
    SingletonTestClass(const SingletonTestClass& ref) = delete;
    SingletonTestClass(SingletonTestClass&& ref) = delete;
    ~SingletonTestClass() = default;
```

Comment: Case 2 is basically equivalent to `{ auto& handler = SingletonTestClass::getInstance(); handler.someApi(); }` Please note the use of `&` to get a *reference* instead of a copy.

Comment: Returning a reference from `getInstance` is fine. The correct invocation for case 1 is `auto &handler = ...getInstance()` and removing the copy constructor will remind them.

Comment: In a lot of cases the best solution is not to use a singleton in the first place but to use dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

> I am interested in knowing how case 2 is working inernally.

Well it is according to the specification of the language. The `SingletonTestClass` instance `handler` which `getInstance()` initializes on the call stack is initialized once and only once and it is given [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/static_storage_duration).

```cpp
static SingletonTestClass& getInstance() {
    static SingletonTestClass handler;
    return handler;
}
```

So it lives through out the lifetime of the program and will only be destructed upon program exit.

> Constructed objects with static storage duration are destroyed and functions registered with std::atexit are called as part of a call to std::exit. The call to std::exit is sequenced before the destructions and the registered functions. [Note: Returning from main invokes std::exit (6.9.3.1). —end note] —-ISO/IEC 14882:2020(E) section 6.9.3.4